# Direct Carrier Billing providers

Tags: mobile, payment-processing, billing

I have been doing some research on payment providers for in-app billing that support direct carrier billing in USA. So far I have found that Google Play support for carriers AT&T, Sprint, and T-Mobile. And WAC support AT&T.

Anyone have been working with or know of any other payment providers?

Conditions:

- Support carrier billing in USA
- Do not use Premium SMS
- And support more than one carrier.

Comment: What is the meaning of Premium SMS and services that may involve SMS?  E.g., Can part of the solution not involve a shortcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest http://bango.com/mobilebillingcoverage/

Comment: link is not valid for now

Answer (score 0):

JunglePay.

See also: http://www.quora.com/Michael-Whel/answers

Comment: JunglePay uses SMS which is not something we are looking for.

Comment: JunglePay has 3 ways to pay. http://www.junglepay.com/features/  Does the platform have to completely devoid of such a feature?

Comment: It is carrier specific billing, and JunglePay is using SMS for this feature, which is what we would like to avoid. It should be a more Direct Billing like Google Play and WAC, but with better coverage on carriers.